# DataTable does not contain definition for AsEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-dataset

Using linq to query a datatable returns the following error:  CS0117: 'DataSet1.map DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'

Project includes reference for System.Data.Datasetextensions.

Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query1 = from mfg_nm in DataSet1.mapDataTable.AsEnumerable()

                     select mfg_nm;
}
```

running it w/out AsEnumerable() results in

```
var query1 = from mfg_nm in DataSet1.mapDataTable

                     select mfg_nm;
```

CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: I think you forgot to accept an Answer as the right Answer. It helps. thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** from "**nuget**" or "**add reference**"

Add this code:

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
```

Answer (score 85):

The [method you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) is in the `System.Data` namespace, so that `using` directive is fine, but you also need a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` *assembly*. Are you *sure* you've got that reference as an *assembly* reference?

It's not clear why you've got a using directive for a `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` *namespace* - does that not raise an error?

What is the exact error with the `AsEnumerable()` call? (I'm surprised about the error you're getting with the second form... that's not the error I'd have expected.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Removed System.data.datasetextensions.  Confirmed System.data.datasetextensions assembly.  Form web.config:   <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

Comment: @user1169290: Can you not just add it under references? I don't know whether having it under web.config makes a difference...

Comment: that's how I added it,I think that added the lines to the config file

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'

Source Error:

Line 32:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 33:     {
Line 34:         var query1 = from mfg_nm in DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable.AsEnumerable()
Line 35: 
Line 36:                     select mfg_nm;

Comment: @user1169290: That's very strange - can you reproduce it in a short but complete console program? If you try `DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable)` what does it show?

Comment: I'm new to this, sorry if it's done incorrectly.  I tried the following:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable);
         }
    }
}

And it returns "The name 'DataSet1' does not exist in the current context.  Not sure what the issue is - I can bind to DataSet1 as an object data source

Comment: @user1169290: You'd have to actually have the data set available in your code. Did you try the other option I mentioned?

Comment: just see the console question.  what was the other option?

Comment: @user1169290: Calling what's normally an extension method explicitly: `DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable)`

Comment: I appreciate your persistence on this.  Made this change to code and received the following errors.

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var query = from mfg_nm in DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable)

         select mfg_nm;
    }

'DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

The name 'DataSet1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user1169290: Okay, well that explains it. You're talking about a type, not an *instance* of the type. You need to actually *have* a DataTable to iterate over...

Comment: I guess that's my confusion - if i have an instance that's populated with data, how do I create a datable to query?

Comment: @user1169290: The DataTable *is* the instance I'm talking about. It sounds like you should take a few steps back from LINQ for the moment, and work out how to get some data from whatever your original data source is first.

Comment: the datatable has data.  I can bind it to gridview or use objectdatasource and the they are populated with data.

Comment: @user1169290: But you don't *have* an instance, as far as we can see. `DataSet1.BIA_device_dp_mapDataTable` is a type (see the compiler error) so where's the instance? Maybe you've got some other variable, but you haven't shown it to us...

Comment: FWIW, in VS2015, have added a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions in a WinForms project. At my `using` directive, `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions`, I get an Intellisense error that `DataSetExtensions` does not exist in `System.Data`, and in my code, `myDataTable.asEnumerable` is underscored in red, with an error that DataTable does not support any such method.  I open the "potential fixes" up at the `using` directive, which offers me the option to "remove unnecessary", and I simply close the popup.  The using directive becomes grayed out, and the error lower in the code disappears.

Comment: But the project won't compile.
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'DataSetExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Tim: Well yes, as my answer says, having a `using` directive (not a `using static`, which would now be valid) for `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions` is invalid. `DataSetExtensions` is a class, not a namespace. Remove that `using` directive. But it's not clear whether you really do have a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` *assembly*. Do you see it in the "References" part of Solution Explorer?

Comment: Yes, the reference is valid, it is in Solution Explorer in the References section. I've removed the using directive. There's something screwy about my machine, I think. I've got the solution in a folder on Dropbox and it compiles at the office but not on my PC at home.  I will reinstall the framework.

Comment: Adding a namespace System.Data in View worked for me

Answer (score 18):

[image]I got this error message: 
'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Added

```
using System.Data;
```

Added "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" to the References section. It resolved the problem.

Comment: This works. for some reason no question is accepted as the right answer. thanks

Answer (score 17):

In all cases where this happens, the reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll was missing. If in doubt, try creating a simple console project targeting .NET 4 with a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, to verify that adding the reference actually works.

Also note that you only need to use the System.Data namespace.

BTW mapDataTable is a DataTable, right?

Comment: Yes, mapdatatable is a datatable

Answer (score 2):

Google search "system.data.datatable does not contain a definition for asenumerable" brought me here, and my trouble was missing:

```
using System.Data;
```

Due to my implement the error message was a bit misleading.  Hence, my answer to this question.  Code was like...

```
public List<mytype> MyMethod(params) {
   return new mynamespace.myclasslib.myclass().GetDataTable(params).AsEnumerable()
      .etc
}
```

Once I tried to explicitly declare the DataTable, it became obvious that I was missing the using statement.

Comment: Just want to add we also should have System.Linq

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

`DataSet1.mapDataTable.Select().AsEnumerable()`

Comment: Please provide some reasoning / explanation why do you think your solution is the appropriate approach.