# Search for a value in datatable

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am trying to find if in any row the column "flag" in dbo.address is set to 1. And then simply set a bool default = true or default = false if its 0.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 dt = AddressData.Data;

 foreach (DataColumn dtColumn in dt.Columns)
            {

            }
```

Or maybe something like this ?

```
    dt.Select("WHERE Flag = " + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use linq ?

```
var default = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(m => m.Field<int>("flag") == 1);
```

Comment: I am getting a 

     'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: I am using Data but DataSetExtensions is not available!?!?

Comment: @xterminal0 no, sorry, it should be in System.Data... What's your framework version ?

Comment: @xterminal0 but look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217272/datatable-does-not-contain-definition-for-asenumerable : you need to add the correct reference.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
dtColumn = dt.Cols.Find("flag = 1");
```

You can then assign a **`bool`** variable to either `true` or `false`.

#### See if this works

```
if (dtColumn["flag"].ToString() == 1)
    default = true;
else
    default = false;
```

Comment: dt does not have the Cols, it has Columns but not the Find function?

Comment: and what about second option