# DataTable does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'

Tags: c#, datatable, observablecollection

I have a DataTable, dt, that I am attempting to convert to an observable collection. **I have included the reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.** 
I am first converting the dt to to a DataView so that I can sort the data. I then convert back to a table. After I try to convert to IEnumerable. When I do this I get the error: **Error  CS1929  'DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'**

Below is what I am trying. I am sure that I am missing something basic here. Again, I have double checkded the references. I have even removed and added the references back in again as my searches so far have indicated that this is the primary problem with this.

```
DataTable dt = GetData();
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "URLId desc"; //URLId is Column1
dt = dv.ToTable();
IEnumerable<MyClass> items = dt.AsEnumerable<MyClass>();  //Error occurs here
IList<MyClass> myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(items);
```

MyClass is a simple collection of string and date fields. Below is the constructor for the class.

```
public MyClass(string urlId, string urlAddress, string displayName)
{
    URLId = urlId;
    CommonName = displayName;
    URLAddress = urlAddress;
    DateLastTouched = DateTime.Now;
    Preview = urlAddress;
    Publish = false;                          
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTable does not contain definition for AsEnumerable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217272/datatable-does-not-contain-definition-for-asenumerable)

Comment: Have you added `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` ?

Comment: I thought I was clear in my post BUT yes, I have added System.Data.DataSetExtensions. The post referenced by Daniel Kelley indicates that the problem was a missing reference to System.Data,DataSetExtensions. That is why I am posting here. :)

Comment: I am not sure of why I am getting down votes. While I am getting the same error, I have triple checked that the reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions has been added.

Comment: I've answered - see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> items = dt.AsEnumerable<MyClass>();
```

but i'm sure `AsEnumerable` is not `AsEnumerable<T>`, hence can you try

```
var items = dt.AsEnumerable().Cast<MyClass>()
```

**EDIT**
(above returns `EnumerableRowCollection<string>` so you may even do

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Cast<MyClass>().AsEnumerable();
```

to get an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`)