# DataTable error - Compiler error 'DataTable' doesn't contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

```
outData = new DataTable();

if(inData.Rows.Count > 0)
{
```

Getting Compiler error :

> 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable'

```
   var result = inData.AsEnumerable().Where(row=>row["Filter Flag"].ToString() == FilterFlag.ToString());
   outData = inData.Clone();   
   foreach(var rowItem in result) 
   {
       outData.ImportRow(rowItem);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataTable does not contain definition for AsEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217272/datatable-does-not-contain-definition-for-asenumerable)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
```

to usings and it will work